# Refined and existential types for runtime values

Tags: scala, shapeless, singleton-type, refinement-type, refined

Suppose I want to map between some strings and integer identifiers, and I want my types to make it impossible to get a runtime failure because someone tried to look up an id that was out of range. Here's one straightforward API:

```
trait Vocab {
  def getId(value: String): Option[Int]
  def getValue(id: Int): Option[String] 
}
```

This is annoying, though, if users will typically be getting their ids from `getId` and therefore know they're valid. The following is an improvement in that sense:

```
trait Vocab[Id] {
  def getId(value: String): Option[Id]
  def getValue(id: Id): String
}
```

Now we could have something like this:

```
class TagId private(val value: Int) extends AnyVal

object TagId {
  val tagCount: Int = 100

  def fromInt(id: Int): Option[TagId] =
    if (id >= 0 && id < tagCount) Some(new TagId(id)) else None
}
```

And then our users can work with `Vocab[TagId]` and not have to worry about checking whether `getValue` lookups failed in the typical case, but they can still look up arbitrary integers if they need to. It's still pretty awkward, though, since we have to write a separate type for each kind of thing we want a vocabulary for.

We can also do something like this with [refined](https://github.com/fthomas/refined):

```
import eu.timepit.refined.api.Refined
import eu.timepit.refined.numeric.Interval.ClosedOpen
import shapeless.Witness

class Vocab(values: Vector[String]) {
  type S <: Int
  type P = ClosedOpen[Witness.`0`.T, S]

  def size: S = values.size.asInstanceOf[S]

  def getId(value: String): Option[Refined[Int, P]] = values.indexOf(value) match {
    case -1 => None
    case i  => Some(Refined.unsafeApply[Int, P](i))
  }

  def getValue(id: Refined[Int, P]): String = values(id.value)
}
```

Now even though `S` isn't known at compile time, the compiler is still able to keep track of the fact that the ids it gives us are between zero and `S`, so that we don't have to worry about the possibility of failure when we go back to values (if we're using the same `vocab` instance, of course).

What I want is to be able to write this:

```
val x = 2
val vocab = new Vocab(Vector("foo", "bar", "qux"))

eu.timepit.refined.refineV[vocab.P](x).map(vocab.getValue)
```

So that users can easily look up arbitrary integers when they really need to. This doesn't compile, though:

```
scala> eu.timepit.refined.refineV[vocab.P](x).map(vocab.getValue)
<console>:17: error: could not find implicit value for parameter v: eu.timepit.refined.api.Validate[Int,vocab.P]
       eu.timepit.refined.refineV[vocab.P](x).map(vocab.getValue)
                                          ^
```

I can make it compile by providing a `Witness` instance for `S`:

```
scala> implicit val witVocabS: Witness.Aux[vocab.S] = Witness.mkWitness(vocab.size)
witVocabS: shapeless.Witness.Aux[vocab.S] = shapeless.Witness$$anon$1@485aac3c

scala> eu.timepit.refined.refineV[vocab.P](x).map(vocab.getValue)
res1: scala.util.Either[String,String] = Right(qux)
```

And of course it fails (at runtime but safely) when the value is out of range:

```
scala> val y = 3
y: Int = 3

scala> println(eu.timepit.refined.refineV[vocab.P](y).map(vocab.getValue))
Left(Right predicate of (!(3 < 0) && (3 < 3)) failed: Predicate failed: (3 < 3).)
```

I could also put the witness definition inside my `Vocab` class and then import `vocab._` to make it available when I need this, but what I really want is to be able to provide `refineV` support without extra imports or definitions.

I've tried various stuff like this:

```
object Vocab {
  implicit def witVocabS[V <: Vocab](implicit
    witV: Witness.Aux[V]
  ): Witness.Aux[V#S] = Witness.mkWitness(witV.value.size)
}
```

But this still requires an explicit definition for each `vocab` instance:

```
scala> implicit val witVocabS: Witness.Aux[vocab.S] = Vocab.witVocabS
witVocabS: shapeless.Witness.Aux[vocab.S] = shapeless.Witness$$anon$1@1bde5374

scala> eu.timepit.refined.refineV[vocab.P](x).map(vocab.getValue)
res4: scala.util.Either[String,String] = Right(qux)
```

I know I could implement `witVocabS` with a macro, but I feel like there should be a nicer way to do this kind of thing, since it seems like a pretty reasonable use case (and I'm not very familiar with refined, so it's entirely possible that I'm missing something obvious).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Turns out that this works as you would like if we make the type parameter `S` concrete by assigning it the singleton type of `values.size` using `shapeless.Witness`:

```
import eu.timepit.refined.api.Refined
import eu.timepit.refined.numeric.Interval.ClosedOpen
import shapeless.Witness

class Vocab(values: Vector[String]) {
  val sizeStable: Int = values.size
  val sizeWitness = Witness(sizeStable)

  type S = sizeWitness.T
  type P = ClosedOpen[Witness.`0`.T, S]

  def size: S = sizeWitness.value

  def getId(value: String): Option[Refined[Int, P]] = values.indexOf(value) match {
    case -1 => None
    case i => Some(Refined.unsafeApply[Int, P](i))
  }

  def getValue(id: Refined[Int, P]): String = values(id.value)
}
```

If Scala would allow singleton types of `AnyVal`s, we could remove `sizeWitness` and define `type S = sizeStable.type`. This limitation is lifted in the [SIP-23 implementation](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/5310).

Using `refineV` now just works even with the path dependant type `vocab.P`:

```
scala> val vocab = new Vocab(Vector("foo", "bar", "baz"))
vocab: Vocab = Vocab@5fae6bb9

scala> refineV[vocab.P](2)
res0: Either[String,eu.timepit.refined.api.Refined[Int,vocab.P]] = Right(2)

scala> refineV[vocab.P](4)
res1: Either[String,eu.timepit.refined.api.Refined[Int,vocab.P]] = Left(Right predicate of (!(4 < 0) && (4 < 3)) failed: Predicate failed: (4 < 3).)

scala> refineV[vocab.P](2).map(vocab.getValue)
res2: scala.util.Either[String,String] = Right(baz)
```

This works since the compiler can now find an implicit `Witness.Aux[vocab.S]` outside the scope of `Vocab` instances:

```
scala> val s = implicitly[shapeless.Witness.Aux[vocab.S]]
s: shapeless.Witness.Aux[vocab.S] = shapeless.Witness$$anon$1@16cd7aa2

scala> s.value
res2: s.T = 3
```

refined now uses this implicit instance to construct a `Validate[Int, vocab.P]` instance which `refineV` uses to decide if an `Int` is valid index for `vocab`.

Comment: I think it'd make sense to undelete your other answer, though, since it's a reasonable alternative approach.

Answer (score 4):

Since the predicate you're using for refining `Int`s is dependant on `Vocab`, one solution is to add an implicit `Witness.Aux[S]` and an alias for `refineV` to this class:

```
import eu.timepit.refined._
import eu.timepit.refined.api.Refined
import eu.timepit.refined.numeric.Interval.ClosedOpen
import shapeless.Witness

class Vocab(values: Vector[String]) {
  type S <: Int
  type P = ClosedOpen[Witness.`0`.T, S]

  def size: S = values.size.asInstanceOf[S]

  def getId(value: String): Option[Refined[Int, P]] = values.indexOf(value) match {
    case -1 => None
    case i  => Some(Refined.unsafeApply[Int, P](i))
  }

  def getValue(id: Refined[Int, P]): String = values(id.value)

  implicit val witnessS: Witness.Aux[S] = Witness.mkWitness(size)

  def refine(i: Int): Either[String, Refined[Int, P]] =
    refineV[P](i)
}
```

Using `Vocab.refine` now doesn't need any additional imports:

```
scala> val vocab = new Vocab(Vector("foo", "bar", "baz"))
vocab: Vocab = Vocab@490b83b3

scala> vocab.refine(1)
res4: Either[String,eu.timepit.refined.api.Refined[Int,vocab.P]] = Right(1)

scala> vocab.refine(3)
res5: Either[String,eu.timepit.refined.api.Refined[Int,vocab.P]] = Left(Right predicate of (!(3 < 0) && (3 < 3)) failed: Predicate failed: (3 < 3).)
```

Comment: Thanks!—this is definitely better than my current alternatives, but I'd still really like to make the `refineV` version work, so I'm going to leave the question open for now.